# Find entities between dates in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I'm using HQL and `javax.persistence`.  In my MySQL database, I have a datetime (e.g. `2018-01-22 18:00:00`).  From the client-side, I'm being passed a date with no time (e.g. `2018-01-20`).  I want to find all the entities where the datetime is between a `startDate` and an `endDate`.

```
public List<BillingRunEntity> getBillingRuns(List<String> accountIds, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT bre " +
               "FROM BillingRunEntity bre " +
               "WHERE bre.accountId in :accountIds " +
               "AND bre.billingDateTime BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate";

    return entityManager
        .createQuery(query, BillingRunEntity.class)
        .setParameter("accountIds", accountIds)
        .setParameter("startDate", startDate)
        .setParameter("endDate", endDate)
        .getResultList();
}
```

And my `BillingRunEntity.java`'s `billingDateTime` field:

```
@Column(name = "billing_date_time")
private ZonedDateTime billingDateTime;
```

---

**1)** Trying to run this query results in the following error.  How do I resolve this, considering I don't care about the time?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-07-03] did not match expected type [java.time.ZonedDateTime (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
```

**2)** Will this query work the way I expect?  I don't care about times here - if the database has `2018-01-22 18:00:00`, and I pass a `startDate` of `2018-01-22` and an end date of `2018-01-23` (or even `2018-01-22`), I'd expect to pull that record.

Comment: You can use LocalDate instead of ZonedDateTime in Entity. Following link will be helpful https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `ZonedDateTime` in the database is always stored in UTC you can simply convert to `LocalDate`

```
ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
ZonedDateTime startTime = startDate.atStartOfDay(utc);
ZonedDateTime endTime = endDate.atStartOfDay(utc).plusDays(1).minusNanos(1);

[...]

    .setParameter("startDate", startTime)
    .setParameter("endDate", endTime)
```

`minusNanos(1)` might be an overkill but the `BETWEEN` operator is inclusive on both ends.

If you don't use the same time zone for all the values in the database you might have to dig into the `billing_date_time` column type used by your table to understand how it handles the time zone information.